# can't connect to mysql8.0 on ubuntu via vmware

Tags: mysql, .net, mysql-workbench, vmware, ubuntu-18.04

I can't appear to make a successful connection with mysql 8.0 that's on Ubunti 18.04 va VMware from my windows 10 host through either visual studio (with the connector/net plugin) or through mysql workbench.

- I've set the various test 
  users to use the mysql_native_password as well as caching_sha2_passwword
- updated mysqld.cnf by setting bind-address = 0.0.0.0 (mysql fails when I edit my.cnf, but there's a symbolic link to /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf that I updated
- did GRANT ALL PRIVELEGES like all the tutorials said; did FLUSH

I can ssh through powershell on my windows host but VS Studio 19 and MYSQL Workbench's simple connect feature doesn't work, when it should.

What could be the issue, aside from reverting down to mysql 5.7 because I has that before upgrading and it still didn't work, thanks.

Comment: in the my.cnf file it should have 
    [mysql]
    bind-address = X.X.X.X 
    #skip-networking 

It should have all three just like that. The "X.X.X.X" is your IP address, or use 0.0.0.0

then restart with "service mysql restart" just as every article on google has suggested and you're set.

Oh, and this only worked for me using the mysql_native_password plugin, not caching_sha2_password. Also, the user was set up with the host as '%' so for instance test@%. Lastly, do everything else above such as the GRANT and FLUSH and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
in the my.cnf file it should have:
[mysql]
bind-address = X.X.X.X 
#skip-networking 

It should have all three just like that. The "X.X.X.X" is your IP address, or use 0.0.0.0

then restart with "service mysql restart" just as every article on google has suggested and you're set.

Oh, and this only worked for me using the mysql_native_password plugin, not caching_sha2_password. Also, the user was set up with the host as '%' so for instance test@%. Lastly, do everything else above such as the GRANT and FLUSH and you're good to go.
```